# How to split this string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to extract latitude and longitude values from the string below:

```
(10.207150961819892, 123.7393569946289)
```

into

```
var lat = 10.207150961819892
var lang = 123.7393569946289
```

Comment: That's because `(` is the first char of that string.

Comment: @Vohuman how to separate them into two?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because this shows no effort on your part. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: Replace `(` and `)` with empty string, split by `,`, then `yourVariable[0]` will return what you want.

Comment: Try trimming off the first and last characters (e.g. with `substr`) before splitting by using a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not splitting yet, and when you use an index on the string, you will get the character at that index, in this case `(`.

What you need to do is, replace `(`, space and `)` and then split on `,`

```
var arr = str.replace(/[() ]/g, "").split(','),
    lat = arr[0],
    lng = arr[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var string = "(10.207150961819892, 123.7393569946289)";
string = string.replace("(","");
string = string.replace(")","");
string = string.replace(" ","");
string = string.split(",");
alert(string[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the parentheses are always the first and last character, you can use `substr` to remove them:

```
str.substr(1, str.length - 2)
```

Then you can split on the comma to get the separate values:

```js
var str = "(10.207150961819892, 123.7393569946289)";

var parts = str.substr(1, str.length - 2).split(', ');
var lat = parts[0];
var lng = parts[1];

// output values in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(lat + '<br>');
document.write(lng + '<br>');
```